# SELECT TOP from CTE based on subtraction of 2 column group by another

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter

I have data which is the results from a bunch of CTE and a query and this is where I am at.

Query (not including all previous CTE tables):

```
SELECT  
    CustomerCode,
    SUBSTRING(SerialNumber, CHARINDEX('-', SerialNumber) + 1, 6) SerialNumber,
    nbServer,
    ISNULL(nbImaging, 0) nbImaging
FROM 
    Magic
WHERE 
    CS_MagicNUmber <> I_MagicNumber
    OR CS_MagicNUmber IS NULL
    OR I_MagicNUmber IS NULL
```

Sample of resulting data:

```
| CustomerNumber | SerialNumber | NBServer | NbImaging |
|:-------------- |:------------ | --------:| ---------:|
| 20032455       | 808225       |        3 |         0 |
| 20032455       | 808224       |        3 |         0 |
| 20032455       | 808223       |        3 |         0 |
| 20032625       | 805779       |       12 |         7 |
| 20032625       | 805781       |       12 |         7 |
| 20032625       | 805778       |       12 |         7 |
| 20032625       | 805782       |       12 |         7 |
| 20032625       | 805783       |       12 |         7 |
| 20032625       | 805785       |       12 |         7 |
| 20032625       | 805786       |       12 |         7 |
| 20032625       | 805780       |       12 |         7 |
```

What I want is to filter those results for each group of records sharing the same `CustomerCode` I.E. to get the `TOP (nbServer - nbImaging)`.

In the sample shown, for `CustomerCode` 20032455 is it simple as the difference is 3 (3-0) and I have 2 rows. But for the following `CustomerCode`, 20032625, I want the 5 first rows (12-7), so those with `SerialNumber` 805779, 805782, 805781, 805778, 805783 .

Of course there are a lot more but I think that shows what I want as a result. I have read multiple examples and also try `PARTITION OVER` but I must confess, nothing works.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: How can I do that?  I don't see any link that allows me to edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is relatively straight forward with `ROW_NUMBER` as that just gives you ascending sequential integers from `1` that you can use in a `WHERE` clause.

I do also tuck the calculation of SerialNumber into a `CROSS APPLY` so I can reference it twice without repeating the expression.

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT  CustomerCode
       ,ca.SerialNumber
       ,nbServer
       ,isnull(nbImaging,0) nbImaging
       ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CustomerCode ORDER BY ca.SerialNumber) rn
FROM Magic
cross apply (select SUBSTRING(SerialNumber,CHARINDEX('-',SerialNumber)+1,6) SerialNumber) ca
WHERE CS_MagicNUmber <> I_MagicNumber
   OR CS_MagicNUmber IS NULL
   OR I_MagicNUmber IS NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE rn <= nbServer - nbImaging
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why partition doesn't work for you.
You want to count up a group of values, this is done by row_number:

```
select ROW_NUMBER()
over (partition by CustomerCode
order by something) AS sort
```

Now, you want to only get the first X records from each group. Since ROW_NUMBER cannot be in a WHERE, you need to wrap the whole thing in a subquery:

```sql
select *
from (
  select *
  , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by CustomerCode order by something) AS sort
  from yourtable
 ) x
where sort <= nbServer - nbImaging
```

EDIT: or what @Martin wrote :)

Comment: I must confess...doesn't work isn't the right term  Don't understand PARTITION OVER is closer to the truth. As in your example, " order by something ", how do you decide what is the somthing?

Comment: Partition By creates a group. So every CustomerCode gets own counter 1, 2, 3, 4. 5. But you always want to have specific sort, for example latest X values, or top 5 values etc. So *something* should be whatever you want to rank your results by. For example SerialNumber, then lowest SerialNumber will get row number 1 etc.

Comment: If you try the query with different order by's and include the actual sort column, you can see how the ranking is performed